# Return response in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to move my logic from controllers to Services, as I am still am new to AngularJS.

I'm trying to get some data from an internal API and return it to my Controller's scope, though the way I am doing it is returning an empty Object.

Here is my controller.

```
cbApp.controller('serversCtrl', function($scope, serversService){
    $scope.servers = serversService.getServers();
    console.log($scope.servers); // returns Object {}
});
```

And here is my service, which I am probably doing wrong.

```
cbApp.service('serversService', function($http){
    var servers = {}
    this.getServers = function(){
        $http.get(BASE_URL + '/api/s').success(function(response){
            servers = response.servers;
        });
        return servers;
    }
});
```

Seems like `servers = response.servers` isn't getting attached after the get function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you are new to AngularJS - you may be new to promises. https://www.promisejs.org/.  Answer below is correct but you should read up first.

Answer (score 2):

Your promise has not completed when `console.log($scope.servers);` runs.

You should still handle the promise in your controller (until you move to using your router's `resolve` but one step at a time).

Here's how you'd change your code:

```
cbApp.controller('serversCtrl', function($scope, serversService){
  serversService.getServers().success(function(servers) {
    $scope.servers = servers;  
   });
});

cbApp.service('serversService', function($http){
    this.getServers = function(){
        return $http.get(BASE_URL + '/api/s');
    }
});
```